# Ajax doesn't execute PHP Form in Internet Explorer and reloads whole index page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm currently interning at an ISP and I'm getting into programming, but it's all very new to me yet.

I always use Chrome for debugging and testing but the official browser of the ISP is Internet Explorer, so it is mandatory for my code to work in IE.

Now: I was so happy yesterday night when the ajax request sending out the values of a textform via PHP into the mysql db worked. But today, back at work, I see that it doesn't work at all in IE.

After I hit `submit` the whole index-page gets reloaded and the values weren't saved into the DB at all.

The code is as follows (the first two ajax requests work greatly, it's the last textarea-ajax-request which doesn't work):

```
$("#display7").click(function() {                
    $.ajax({  
        type: "GET",
        url: "cabcab2.php",          
        dataType: "html",                  
        success: function(response){ 
            $("#responsecontainer").show().html(response);  
            $(".name").on("click", function() {
                var category_id = {};
                category_id['id'] = $(this).attr("id");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'display2.php',
                    data: category_id,
                    success: function( response2 ) {
                        $("#details").toggle().html( response2 );
                    }
                });
            })

            //function to insert textarea**
            function insertTextarea() {
                var boardInfo = $( "<form id='boardComment'><textarea rows='4' cols='50'></textarea><input type='submit' value='Submit'><input type='reset' value='Cancel'></form>");   
                $( this ).html(boardInfo);
                $(".boardinfo").off();
                console.log("boardinfo click event off");
                $("#boardComment").on( "submit", function( event ) {
                    console.log( "Handler for submit called." );
                    event.preventDefault(); 
                    var change_id = {};
                    console.log($(this).parent().attr("id"));
                    console.log( $(this).find("textarea").val());
                    change_id['id'] = $(this).parent().attr("id");
                    change_id['comment'] = $(this).find("textarea").val();
                    console.log($(this).parent());
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "boardinfo2.php",
                        data: change_id,
                        success: function( response2 ) {
                            alert("Your comment has been saved!");
                            $("#" + change_id['id']).html("<img src='http://'>");
                            $( ".boardinfo" ).on( "click", insertTextarea );
                        }
                    });         
                });
                $("#boardComment").on( "reset", function( ) {
                    $( this ).html("<img src='http://'>");
                    $( ".boardinfo" ).on( "click", insertTextarea );
                });
            }   
            $( ".boardinfo" ).on( "click", insertTextarea );
        }
    }); 
});
```

The textarea loads in IE, but when I click submit, the WHOLE page (-> the index.html) gets reloaded and the values weren't saved to the DB.

Is there any solution to this problem? I really like how it looks and feels in Chrome and Firefox, so I don't want to drop the code.

Would be very happy if someone knew something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [preventing default behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault)?
IE most likely just submits the form thus making a page reload. You'll need to prevent it from happening.

```
$("#display7").click(function(event) { 
    // tell browser to stop executing any default behaviour for this event
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: thank you for helping!! i already had the event.preventDefault(); underneath the textarea function - i now tried it to add it to the parent, like you suggested, to $("#display7").click(function(event) {, doesn't work either tho sadly..